# MySQL - Order substring digits lowest to highest

Tags: mysql, substring, sql-order-by

I want to order a column by its values, lowest to highest. However the column has a prefix set, so that its contents can look like this `SR1001000`. I've figured that ifi want to order this, i would need to remove the prefix. So for now my Query looks like this:

```
SELECT a2t_import.*,SUBSTRING(a2t_import.a2t_vare_nr, 3) as partial_vare_nr 
FROM a2t_import 
ORDER BY partial_vare_nr ASC`
```

However i also need to only get the rows where the column has a specific prefix which i get by adding a regular expression like so

```
SELECT a2t_import.*,SUBSTRING(a2t_import.a2t_vare_nr, 3) as partial_vare_nr 
FROM a2t_import 
WHERE a2t_vare_nr REGEXP '^(SR)+[0-9]+' 
ORDER BY partial_vare_nr ASC
```

This gives me the correct output where the above example looks like this `1001000`, but the sorting is not what I'd expect.

I get the following output

```
10002000
1001000
...
```

As you can see, the first row is clearly of a higher number than the second. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the sorting is off that currently MySQL is treating your computed column as text, not as numerical data.  This has the following unwanted side effect:

```
10002000
1001000
   ^
```

The value `10002000` appears first, because it would appear before `1001000` in a dictionary.  One trick to workaround this would be to also use the lengths of the strings when sorting.  Consider the following comparison:

```
1000200
1001000
```

Now `1000200` comes before `1001000`, and the lexicographic sort agrees with the numeric sort.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT a2t_import.*,
       SUBSTRING(a2t_import.a2t_vare_nr, 3) AS partial_vare_nr
FROM a2t_import
WHERE a2t_vare_nr REGEXP '^(SR)+[0-9]+'
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(partial_vare_nr),     -- shortest strings first
         partial_vare_nr                   -- lexigraphical sort among strings
                                           -- of same length - agrees with numeric sort
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick ! And good explanation, hadnot tought about it as being text :-)